The order structure of $\sigma$-algebras
A classical result in set theory says that if $A$ and $B$ are two well-ordered sets, then either $A$ embeds into a proper initial segment of $B$, or $B$ embeds into a proper initial segment of $A$, or $A$ and $B$ are order-isomorphic.
Since $\sigma$-algebras have quite a restrictive structure, I was wondering to what extent an analogous result might hold, thinking of a $\sigma$-algebra purely as a set partially ordered by inclusion (and embeddings here are taken to be order-preserving injections- I am already aware that not all $\sigma$-algebras on the same set are comparable via inclusion as subsets). More precisely, let $A$, $B$ be $\sigma$-algebras over $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Which, if any, of the following results hold?

There is an embedding $f$ (possibly an isomorphism) of $A$ into $B$, or of $B$ into $A$.
The embedding $f$ in (1) can be chosen to be an isomorphism with a proper initial segment; that is, if $U\in A$, $V\in B$, and $V\subset f(U)$, then there is $W\in A$ with $f(W)=V$.
If both of the above hold, is there an even stronger result analogous to the structure of the ordinals (or perhaps to the cardinals)?

Here are my observations so far:

(1) and (2) are all obviously true if all $\sigma$-algebras above are taken to be finite.
I have a feeling that (2) is false in general. I have not managed to construct an actual counterexample, but the following example hopefully illustrates what I think might go wrong. Let $X$ be the second uncountable ordinal $\omega_1+1$, and let $A$ be the sigma-algebra generated by all open right-rays of $X$ (i.e. intervals of the form $(\alpha,\omega_1]$). Then $\{\omega_1\}$ is not measurable, and any initial segment of $A$ which contains an interval of the form $(\alpha,\omega_1]$ must be uncountable, so cannot be order-isomorphic to a finite sigma-algebra. This isn't quite a counterexample to (3) because every finite left-ray of $X$ is measurable here, but I have a feeling there might be some counterexample along these lines in which every initial segment is uncountable.
I have little hope for (3). A slightly pathological example is as follows: Let $X=\mathbb Z\cup(0.5,\infty)$, and let $Y=\mathbb R$. Let $A,B$ be their respective Borel $\sigma$-algebras. Then $A$ embeds into $B$, and $B$ embeds into $A$, but they are not order-isomorphic, since $A$ has both countable and uncountable maximal chains, whereas every maximal chain in $B$ is uncountable; so $\sigma$-algebras do not have a trichotomy property as ordinals do, and equal cardinality does not imply order-isomorphism. This post is also related, which characterises the possible cardinalities of infinite $\sigma$-algebras as those which are at least the size of the continuum and have countable cofinality. I leave part (3) in this question, just in case there might be a generalisation I am missing.


Since you compare sigma-algebras on different sets, maybe a better term would be measurable space. This is by definition a pair consisting of a set and a sigma-algebra on it. These objects are the subject of your questions. You can also then research for properties of the category of measurable spaces $\mathbf{Meas}$.

But on the other hand, there one usually takes different morphisms. Why is (1) trivial for finite sigma-algebras?

@MartinBrandenburg Any finite $\sigma$-algebra is isomorphic (in the OP’s sense) to $\mathcal{P}(F)$ for some finite set $F$.

By the way, your comment on your third question is simply wrong. $\mathbb{Z} \cup (0.5, \infty)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are Borel isomorphic to each other, so their Borel $\sigma$-algebras are isomorphic. I’m not sure what you had in mind when you mentioned “$A$ has both countable and uncountable maximal chains”, but that is simply false.

(Though there are examples of $\sigma$-algebras that embed into each other but are not order-isomorphic. For example, the $\sigma$-algebra $A$ on $\mathbb{R} \sqcup \mathbb{R}$ consisting of sets whose intersections with the first copy of $\mathbb{R}$ are Borel and whose intersections with the second copy of $\mathbb{R}$ are arbitrary, and $B = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfy this condition. Even simpler, $A$ being the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $B = \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ work.)

$1$ is already false. Say, let $A = \mathcal{P}(\omega_2)$ and $B$ be the countable-cocountable $\sigma$-algebra on $2^{2^{\omega_2}}$. Then any well-ordered chain in $B$ has order type at most $\omega_1 + \omega_1$ - the initial segment consisting of countable sets can only have order type at most $\omega_1$, and similarly the final segment consisting of cocountable sets can only have order type at most $\omega_1$. But $A$ clearly contains a well-ordered chain of order type $\omega_2 > \omega_1 + \omega_1$, so $A$ does not embed into $B$. $B$ does not embed into $A$ either, as $B$ has cardinality $2^{2^{\omega_2}}$ whereas $A$ has cardinality $2^{\omega_2} < 2^{2^{\omega_2}}$.

Actually, changing $\omega_2$ to $\omega_1$ would work just as well, seeing $\mathcal{P}(\omega_1)$ already has a well-ordered chain of order type $\omega_1 + \omega_1 + 1$.

Great answer! Thanks.
